Probability involving identical objects. I am not able to understand how the Ncr formula is being applied below for counting identical objects.
Question: A bag contains 5 identical red coins, 6 identical yellow coins and 8 identical blue coins.  If 3 coins are picked up randomly from the bag, what is the probability that there is at least one yellow coin?

Official explanation:
Probability of atleast one coin to be yellow = 1-P(No coin is yellow)
=1-$\frac{\binom{13}{3}}{\binom{19}{3}}$
=$\frac{683}{969}$
My question is how are we applying the Ncr method to count identical objects when it is applicable only for counting distinct objects.  My teacher said that in most of the cases for probability questions, it does not matter if we take identical objects as distinct, but I am not able to think of any reason why this is the case.

We can always label the objects to make them distinct.

Thanks, but by labelling aren't we changing what the question demands us to calculate ? The balls won't be identical in that case

The identical coins are distinct. Otherwise, they would be the same coin.

What matters here is how many of the yellow coins are selected.  Since we are selecting without replacement, the number of yellow coins we select does not depend on whether or not we can distinguish between them.  Moreover, otherwise indistinguishable objects can be distinguished by their positions or the order in which we select them.

As suggested in other comments, putting labels on the balls should not change any of the given probabilities, since you can ignore or not ignore the labels, and either way the underlying process/math is the same. By the way, do you have your own proposed solution? And, if so, does it give the same answer or a different answer than the "official explanation"? (I can think of other ways to get to the same solution.)
